# How can I get this condition met for a loop that changes a string to end?

Tags: ruby, string, loops

I'm comparing a word against another string, which is changing by looping through the alphabet and inserting each letter at every position of the word.

```
@position_counter = 0
```

EDIT: Here is the code that letter_loop is running through.

```
@array = ["amethod", "variable", "block"]

def word_list_loop
  @match_counter = 0
  @array.each do |word|
    letter_loop(word)
  end
  puts @match_counter
end
```

CLOSE EDIT

```
def letter_loop(word)
  ("a".."z").each do |letter|
     word_plus_letter = @word.dup
     word_plus_letter.insert(@position_counter, letter)
     @match_counter+=1 if word.match(/\A#{word_plus_letter}\z/)
  end
  @position_counter+=1
  letter_loop(word) unless @position_counter == (@word.length + 1) 
end
```

The word I'm using for the argument is `"method"`. But when I run this, I am getting a `index 7 out of string (IndexError)`. Its looping through the alphabet for each position correctly, but it doesn't seem to get caught with the `unless @position_counter == (@word.length + 1)` to end.

I've tried a few other ways, with an if statement, etc, but I'm not able to get the method to complete itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many times are you running `letter_loop`? Are you sure the error happens in the first run? From what I see, if you call it a second time without resetting `@position_counter` to zero, it will begin with `@word.length + 1` producing the exact error you see. Other than that, I couldn't find any problems with your code (ran just fine here on the first run).

**Update:** since you're using a recursive solution, and `position_counter` does not represent the state of your program (just the state of your method call), I'd suggest not declaring it as `@position_counter` but as an optional parameter to your method:

```
def letter_loop(word, position_counter=0)
  ("a".."z").each do |letter|
     word_plus_letter = @word.dup
     word_plus_letter.insert(position_counter, letter)
     @match_counter+=1 if word.match(/\A#{word_plus_letter}\z/)
  end
  position_counter+=1
  letter_loop(word, position_counter) unless position_counter == (@word.length + 1) 
end
```

If you can't/don't want to do this, just reset it before/after each use, like I suggested earlier, and it will work fine:

```
@array.each do |word|
  @position_counter = 0
  letter_loop(word)
end
```

(though I wouldn't recommend this second approach, since if you forget to reset it somewhere else your method will fail again)

Comment: You're right, I didn't run this separately. It looks like the issue is in the code `letter_loop` is running in. I just updated the question with the code.

Comment: That's it then! However, I'd suggest using an optional parameter instead, so you don't forget to reset `position_counter` somewhere. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are calling `letter_loop` from within `@array.each`, but you don't reset `@position_counter` to zero on each iteration of the `@array.each` loop.

If that doesn't fix your problem, add something like this as the first line of `letter_loop`:

```
puts "letter_loop word=#{word}, position=#{@position_counter}, matches=#{@match_counter}"
```

Then run the program and examine the output leading up to the `IndexError`.